# Handle JavaScript function inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am using JavaScript function inside of while loop. That loop prints list of records and edit button. When click on edit button there is function (Lets say `editBtnClicked(id)`).
**Problem: It is getting called to there but page is refreshing automatically.**

What is happening over there I couldn't find? Someone have a look at this:

```
function editBtnClicked(id) {
                console.log("Edit Section");
                $(".showData").css("display", "none");
                $(".showInputField").css("display", "block"); }

<button id="edit" name="Edit" value="Edit" class="edit btn btn-info"onclick="editBtnClicked('<%=id%>');">
```

Comment: I can only guess, because there is too much info missing..., that the `<button />` is part of a form. If there is no `type` defined on a `<button />` element it acts like a submit button. Just add `type="button"` and you should be fine.

Comment: And you should avoid using the `onXXX` attributes to assign event handlers. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead. The `id` could be added as a `data-`*` attribute which would then be available with [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defualt, [`button` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element) are `type="submit"`. If you don't want it to be a submit button, use `type="button"` instead:

```
<button type="button" id="edit" name="Edit" value="Edit" class="edit btn btn-info"onclick="editBtnClicked('<%=id%>');">
```

---

If for some reason you want it to continue to be a submit button, but you want to prevent submission: In your `onclick` attribute, pass the `event` into your function:

```
<button id="edit" name="Edit" value="Edit" class="edit btn btn-info"onclick="editBtnClicked(event, '<%=id%>');">
```

That `event` will exist within the context created for that call, either as a global (Chrome, IE) or as a local (Firefox).

Then in your handler, use `preventDefault`:

```
function editBtnClicked(event, id) {
    $.Event(event).preventDefault(); // Note the jQuery event wrapper
    console.log("Edit Section");
    $(".showData").css("display", "none");
    $(".showInputField").css("display", "block");
}
```

---

That said, I'd probably change this up completely and use *event delegation* instead of an `onclick` attribute.

On some container all these buttons will be in:

```
$("selector for the container").on("click", "button.edit", editBtnClicked);
```

...and when outputting them (note I've removed the `id` — you said this was a loop, you can't have the same `id` more than once!):

```
<button type="button" type="button" value="Edit" class="edit btn btn-info" data-id="'<%=id%>'">
```

And in the function:

```
function editBtnClicked() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id"); // Get the ID
    console.log("Edit Section");
    $(".showData").css("display", "none");
    $(".showInputField").css("display", "block");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- attach preventDefault() to click event or return false at the end of function to prevent submitting. In second case you should write onclick="return editBtnClicked('<%=id%>')"

2- Do not put your function inside the loop. Consider using ID inside your function so you wont need to repeat function inside the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Please use PreventDefault for reference :http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

```
  function editBtnClicked(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("Edit Section");
            $(".showData").css("display", "none");
            $(".showInputField").css("display", "block"); 
  }

 <button id="edit" name="Edit" value="Edit" class="edit btn btn-info"onclick="editBtnClicked('<%=id%>');">
```